# How do I pick title and images from the latest WordPress articles?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am customizing my WordPress home page by editing the file index.php. The point is that I want to have my custom html design to show the latest posts and I want to show each article differently, depending on how old it is.
As you can see I am creating some Windows 8-like "tiles" but I don't know how to pick from the WordPress the titles and image URLs from the latest articles. In the big tile I would like to show the latest one, in the smaller one the second to last..etc

Comment: Why would you edit the `index.php` file? This is what `template-homepage.php` is for, and then Make a new page, and then go to settings->reading and for the "home page" select your "page" that you creatd then make whatever modificatins you need in `template-homepage.php`

Comment: Ok, but even if I use the template-homepage.php how do I tell WordPress where to put titles and image urls?

Answer (score 0):

You can query_post and show 1, then offset the second loop by 1 so you have two different loops and the second loop will ignore the first post.

```
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=1' );
```

and

```
query_posts( 'offset=1' );
```

If you need pagination still on the page, you should look into this article.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination